# Linux sort of the target plus lines above and below it

Tags: linux, sorting, date, logging, grep

I've got an output file created by grepping thousands of log files and then sorting and de-duping them (sort, uniq) based on successful logins of the "guest" account.

I'm trying to figure out a way to sort entries based on date while ALSO keeping the 4 lines above and 1 line below together (everything in between the delimiters "-+-+-") for the entries. For example:

> -+-+-
>
> Session thread 387746 for Windows account 'DATASERVER\guest' from 116.111.145.182:51007:
>     Logon attempt 1 for user name 'guest' with logon method 'password' succeeded.
>
> 000051568433 2015-07-04 02:24:19.324083 UTC WinSSHD 5.23 [060] Info
>
> -+-+-
>
> Session thread 417661 for Windows account 'DATASERVER\guest' from 168.1.107.236:61972:
>     Logon attempt 1 for user name 'guest' with logon method 'password' succeeded.
>
> 000050566540 2015-09-28 12:29:31.424072 UTC WinSSHD 5.23 [060] Info
>
> -+-+-
>
> Session thread 9807 for Windows account 'DATASERVER\guest' from 36.80.132.130:49683:
>     Logon attempt 1 for user name 'guest' with logon method 'password' succeeded.
>
> 000037599714 2014-12-04 18:39:15.269782 UTC WinSSHD 5.23 [060] Info
>
> -+-+-
>
> Session thread 1697 for Windows account 'DATASERVER\guest' from 119.147.251.150:48215:
>     Logon attempt 1 for user name 'guest' with logon method 'password' succeeded.
>
> 000000230681 2013-11-21 11:23:52.165653 UTC WinSSHD 5.23 [049] Info
>
> -+-+-

Is it possible to sort them based on YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS.micro while keeping all 6 lines of each entry together as a whole and reorder the entire file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to whoever answered this question last week (the response now appears deleted).

After playing around with your answer, here's a working solution (well, close enough for me, because I don't really care about the microseconds after the `HH:MM:DD` part of the log entries).

```
grep -Po ".*(?=UTC)" Filename.txt | sort -k 2,2 | xargs -I {} grep -B4 -A1 '{}' Filename.txt
```